# MUI: (Autocomplete) The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form, yup

I get this message in the console when I'm trying to load data into an MUI Autocomplete.
I'm using react-hook-form and yup to validate my form
[Image with the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Held.png)

I created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-load-data-phcped) with my example.
When I click on the edit button, I'd like to load all user data into the field, even including the country in AutocompleteField

I have been using these properties:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
  option.value === value.value
}
defaultValue={value}
```

And they are throwing errors when I'm creating a new user

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `isOptionEqualToValue` is saying value will always be one of the options.

You can add `freeSolo` prop, which says the value can be `string` or one of your options. It will fix the warning. You can find more about `freeSolo` over [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#free-solo)